# Installing a "Healthy" button on our site, as a partnership with RunKeeper

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I've been in communication with RunKeeper off and on for the past couple of months, and they recently approached me about a new "Healthy" button they're trying to launch. The idea is similar to a Facebook "Like" button, where if you mark something as "Healthy" it will show up in your RunKeeper Fitness Feed and all your friends on RunKeeper can see it. What do you guys think about installing it on our site so that people can share our content with their friends on RunKeeper?

Below is a mockup of what it would look like. I can't promise that this will happen, but I wanted to get feedback from the Fitness & Nutrition community before I go any further with this idea.

[image: healthy button]

Comment: Well, with a few upvotes and no comments or replies, it looks like at least nobody outright *hates* the idea? :)

Comment: Haha it appears that way. We actually discussed it in chat a while back though and the idea was well received.

Comment: @Lauren I saw the button this morning. I guess it's official now?

Comment: It's official! They just made the announcement on http://blog.runkeeper.com/, so I'm working on a blog post announcing it to our community. Should be up in a couple hours!

Comment: Great work @Lauren :D

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old at this point, but I wanted to mention that not only is this a good idea, it's a pretty great idea. Given that one of the points of the "beta" run is to increase awareness of the site, partnering with existing fitness-related websites seems like a great way to help get this site propelled to "gold master" status or whatever they call it around here.

Answer (score 2):

I remember discussing this in chat with Lauren and Ivo. I think it's a great idea to have this on our site and let users share this kind of activity with others. It might also end up drawing more people to the site to ask and answer questions which is always worthwhile. From what I've been reading about them on [BostInno.com](http://bostinno.com/), they have certainly been doing a lot of work and doing tons of [service integrations](http://bostinno.com/2011/08/04/runkeeper-on-its-way-to-becoming-the-health-tracking-solution-with-11-new-partners/) with their [Health Graph API](http://bostinno.com/2012/01/30/runkeeper-adds-9-new-partners-to-healthgraph-api/). RunKeeper looks like it will be a strong and healthy (pardon the pun) company in the upcoming future.

I think an important consideration for this new feature is, **"Does this make the internet a better place?"**  and my answer is a resounding, "**YES**."

Edit: Looks like the RunKeeper button has launched on Fitness! An annoucement was also posted on the [RunKeeper blog](http://blog.runkeeper.com/new-feature/healthy-button-bookmarklet/) this morning about the launch of the button.

Comment: Let's hope participation one Fitness.SE is also considered part of their Health Graph ;)